# Named Parameter with AND/OR in CONTAINS query is not working

Tags: oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

I am using Oracle Text for searching in my web application. I have configured Oracle Text by creating Data Store and Index.

This is my query

```
select * from PROFILE where CONTAINS(FIRST_NAME,:firstName OR :secondName,1)>0;
```

Every time I get the following exception `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.`

But after replacing `:firstName` and `:secondName` by any string it's working perfectly.

Also its working perfectly with one parameter.
`select * from PROFILE where contains(FIRST_NAME,:firstName,1)>0`

The above code is working. But after adding `OR :secondName`, the result is `ORA-00907`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Oracle Text documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24435/query.htm#autoId1), it seems [`CONTAINS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/csql.htm#i997503) is a defined as a regular function with three parameters (the last one optional):

> ```
> CONTAINS(
>          [schema.]column,
>          text_query    [VARCHAR2|CLOB]
>          [,label       NUMBER])
> RETURN NUMBER;
> ```

The `text_query` parameter is a regular string *interpreted* as a [phrase](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24435/query.htm#autoId12). Thus you should write:

```
select * from PROFILE where contains(FIRST_NAME, :search_query, 1)>0
```

And bind the value `FOO OR BAR` to the variable `search_query` since the `OR` keyword is not part of the SQL query in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should better use

```
select * from PROFILE where CONTAINS(FIRST_NAME,:firstName ,1)>0  
OR CONTAINS(FIRST_NAME,:secondName,1)>0
```

Comment: This will not work because of the repetition of FIRST_NAME I think.  It will show error `ORA-29907: found duplicate labels in primary invocations`